# Changing wordpress home folder

Tags: wordpress

Could anyone please help me to change the home folder of wordpress from `/var/www/html` to `/home/saurav/wordpress`?

Answer (score 4):

1. Move everything from `/var/www/html` to `/home/saurav/wordpress`:

   ```
   sudo mv /var/www/html/* /home/saurav/wordpress/
   ```
2. `/var/www/html` is now empty, remove it:

   ```
   sudo rmdir /var/www/html
   ```
3. Create a symbolic link from `/var/www/html` to `/home/saurav/wordpress`:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /home/saurav/wordpress /var/www/html
   ```

Comment: Thank You  But how do I now access the website.  
locathost/wordpress says error requested URL not found

Comment: `http://localhost` now corresponds to `/home/saurav/wordpress`. So `http://localhost/wordpress` would correspond to /home/saurav/wordpress/wordpress`, so you need to go up one step.

Comment: If you think I have given an acceptable answer, please check the tick mark next to it (underneath the vote count) to mark the question as "answered".

Comment: "Create a symbolic link" - Although it would be preferable to fix/update the `DocumentRoot` and any associated `<Directory>` containers (if any) in the server config instead.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is create a new virtual host in Apache and then move all file to a new directory .
To do it you can follow this guide step by step. Then you will be able to access WordPress with virtual domain from your favorite directory.

1. Create the `/home/user/www/mydomain.local/public_html`  directory and move your site's files to the new directory:

   ```
   mkdir -p /home/user/www/mydomain.local/public_html
   sudo mv /var/www/html/* /home/user/www/mydomain.local/public_html
   ```

   Note: Replace `user` with your username or home directory name and  `mydomain.local` with your favorite name of local domain. This use for domain name of your local site `public_html` directory is optional but recommended, so create it.
2. Make yourself the owner of the files contained in `/var/www/example.com/public_html`:

   ```
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example.com/public_html
   ```

   The `$USER` variable will take the value of the user you are currently logged in with when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. By doing this, our regular user now owns the `public_html` subdirectories where we will be storing our content.
3. Change the permissions of the files in `/home/user/www/` :

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 755 /home/user/www/
   ```

   Your web server should now have the permissions it needs to serve content, and your user should be able to create content within the necessary folders.
4. Create a virtual host for your site:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.local.conf
   ```

   Add something like this in the file and save it:

   ```xml
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     ServerName mydomain.local
     ServerAlias www.mydomain.local
     DocumentRoot /home/user/www/mydomain.local/public_html
     ErrorLog /home/user/www/mydomain.local/error.log
     CustomLog /home/user/www/mydomain.local/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
5. Now enable your site:

   ```
   sudo a2ensite mydomain.local.conf
   ```
6. Open the local host file and add your domain point to localhost IP (127.0.0.1):

   ```
   sudo /etc/hosts
   ```

   Add this at the end of the file:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 mydomain.local
   ```
7. Finally restart Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

You should be able to see the result by typing `http://mydomain.local` in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have it exactly where it belongs. Placing a WordPress in a user's home directory is an improper use of the Linux filesystem.

The `/var` directory tree is where data that is likely to change is stored. Various databases, spool files, log files, and similar. are located here.

WordPress is a CMS written in PHP and paired with a database. It has system-wide dependencies.

Separating user data from system-wide data avoids redundancy and makes backups of important files straightforward. It's also this way for security purposes. Going further into those is a separate discussion.

The `/root` is meant for just root user and `/home` is for all the remaining users. Each user home directory is important and frequently used directory for that user, we have alias name for it. This alias is set to `~`. Think of your home directory like your personal documents folder, or the stuff you save to your desktop, your music, videos, stuff you're working on.